# long/LONG delays in response of alpine commands

Tags: linux

I am using alpine on a linux machine and the emails are stored on a server where I use outlook. So I can read email both using outlook and using alpine. This has worked fine. But recently alpine commands have started taking 'forever' as 'fetching folders' takes forever, as does opening up a folder that was not opened before. This problem persisted for a week, disappeared and is now back again.  there is no problem reading the emails with outlook.